# How can I infinitely print a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a program for my website where you can see a program "infinitely" print text. I want it to create a random variable, it doesn't matter that it is just random gibberish, and then write it out on the site itself. Right now I have created a piece of code that can create the gibberish, but I'm struggling with the printing part. I want it to show the previously generated gibberish as well, preferably on the same line. As an example:

1. gibberish = wasd
2. print gibberish
3. generate the new gibberish
4. combine gibberish 1 and gibberish 2
5. print the combined gibberish
6. repeat!

I have tried multiple pieces of code but I couldn't figure it out. It is probably a very simple loop so sorry in advance -_-

This is my latest attempt:

```js
function gibberish() {
        var randomsequence = '';
        var followup = '';
            function makeid(length) {
               var output  = '';
               var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
               var charactersLength = letters.length;
               for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                  output += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
               }
               return output;
            }   
            var monkeyoutput1 = '';
            var stringoutput = monkeyoutput1 + makeid(Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)) ;
            monkeyoutput1 = stringoutput;
            
            document.getElementById("monkeybox").innerHTML = monkeyoutput1;
            
            //document.getElementById("monkeybox").innerHTML = makeid(Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)) ;
}
setInterval(gibberish, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
    <h1> text </h1><p id="monkeybox"> placeholder text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added the innerHTML before the new text so it appends it

```js
function gibberish() {
        var randomsequence = '';
        var followup = '';
            function makeid(length) {
               var output  = '';
               var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
               var charactersLength = letters.length;
               for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                  output += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
               }
               return output;
            }   
            var monkeyoutput1 = '';
            var stringoutput = monkeyoutput1 + makeid(Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)) ;
            monkeyoutput1 = stringoutput;
            
            document.getElementById("monkeybox").innerHTML = document.getElementById("monkeybox").innerHTML + monkeyoutput1;
            
            //document.getElementById("monkeybox").innerHTML = makeid(Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 1)) ;
                }
setInterval(gibberish, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
    <h1> text </h1><p id="monkeybox"> placeholder text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I feel quite stupid rn, but hey I learned a new gimmick :)